# Spring boot app - How to make database connection?

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc, driver

I'm trying to create my first Spring Boot application and I have an issu with database connection.

At the run, I have an

> java.sql.SQLException : Driver.com.musql.jdbc.Driver which return null

( the complete error at the bottom)

When I'm connecting to my localhost's database without Spring Boot this is working perfectly, I tested that with this piece of code :

> ```
>   try {
>         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
>         java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager
>         .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/logsdb","logsdb", "logsdb");
>         System.out.println("connection ok");
>         System.out.println(connection.getCatalog());
>     } catch (SQLException e) {
>         System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
>         e.printStackTrace();
>         return;
>     }
> ```

This return the database I created in localhost.

But it is not working with Spring boot.

I followed this tutorial : http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/#scratch

[Screen of the structure of the project on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTG6f.png)

**My Pom.xml** :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.toto.logsDB</groupId>
<artifactId>logsDB</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**My "application.properties" :**

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/logsdb
spring.datasource.username=logsdb
spring.datasource.password=logsdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**The error :**

```
        2016-01-27 14:18:12.396  INFO 3436 --- [           main] c.toto.logsDB.application.Application  : Starting Application on EB-OR6105938 with PID 3436 (C:\workspaceLogs\target\classes started by GGFF7580 in C:\workspaceLogs)
    2016-01-27 14:18:12.398  INFO 3436 --- [           main] c.toto.logsDB.application.Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2016-01-27 14:18:12.425  INFO 3436 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@10f93f9: startup date [Wed Jan 27 14:18:12 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    2016-01-27 14:18:12.807  WARN 3436 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
    2016-01-27 14:18:12.814  WARN 3436 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
    2016-01-27 14:18:13.112 ERROR 3436 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

    **java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@9ff430 returned null for URL:jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/logsdb**
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:326) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:289) [spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:329) [spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:95) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDatabaseInitializer.getDatabaseType(BatchDatabaseInitializer.java:71) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDatabaseInitializer.initialize(BatchDatabaseInitializer.java:50) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at com.toto.logsDB.application.Application.main(Application.java:37) [classes/:na]

    2016-01-27 14:18:13.113  WARN 3436 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDatabaseInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
    2016-01-27 14:18:13.114  INFO 3436 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
    2016-01-27 14:18:13.115 ERROR 3436 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDatabaseInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is **java.lang.IllegalStateException**: **Unable to detect database type**
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at com.toto.logsDB.application.Application.main(Application.java:37) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDatabaseInitializer.getDatabaseType(BatchDatabaseInitializer.java:74) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDatabaseInitializer.initialize(BatchDatabaseInitializer.java:50) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is **org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@9ff430 returned null for URL:jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/logsdb**
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:302) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:329) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:95) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDatabaseInitializer.getDatabaseType(BatchDatabaseInitializer.java:71) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
    Caused by: **org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection**; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@9ff430 returned null for URL:jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/logsdb
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:289) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@9ff430 returned null for URL:jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/logsdb
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:326) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 29 common frames omitted

    2016-01-27 14:18:13.117  INFO 3436 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/workspaceLogs/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-batch/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-batch-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.13/slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.13/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.13/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.13/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.3.3/hsqldb-2.3.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-core/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/com/ibm/jbatch/com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi/1.0/com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/javax/batch/javax.batch-api/1.0/javax.batch-api-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.7/xstream-1.4.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.2/jettison-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-infrastructure/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/retry/spring-retry/1.1.2.RELEASE/spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.30/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.30/tomcat-juli-8.0.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/GGFF7580/Documents/maven2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar]
```

I read a lot of posts on stackoverflow but I wasn't able to find the good solution, if you have an idea..

Best regards,
Jimmy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a spelling error in your jdbc url. It should be (notice the `:`):

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logsdb
```

Comment: Oh I'm such an idiot, I thought about a lot of things but I didn' notice this.. lol thanks a lot fateddy !

Comment: What was the problem? That he used 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: No - the error was an invalid jdbc-url. Just take a look at the question - section "application.properties"

Comment: @fateddy How would you catch a exception if you provided the wrong user or pass?

Comment: What do you mean? In this case fail fast would be the best option (so let the exception bubble up and stop the application startup).

Answer (score 1):

Change your property to `spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logsdb`. You missed a `:` after  `mysql` in `spinrg.datasource.url` and hence your got the error `java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@9ff430 returned null for URL:jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/logsdb`